# Get the class field name in Java

Tags: java, spring, java-module, java-14

```
public class Product{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    // Getters and setters..
}
```

From the above class, I want to get the field name of description during runtime:

```
Query query = new Query();
        if (productSearchCriteria.getDescription().isPresent()) {
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("description").is(productSearchCriteria.getDescription().get()));
        }
```

Currently, I have hardcoded the name, but it should be dynamic, because if someone renames or changes the property name, this will not work.

While looking around, I found a [reflection-util](https://github.com/cronn-de/reflection-util) library.

```
 String numberProperty = PropertyUtils.getPropertyName(Product.class, Product::getDescription);
```

This gave me an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class domain.Product$ByteBuddy$QIcFk1aK cannot be cast to class domain.Product (domain.Product$ByteBuddy$QIcFk1aK is in unnamed module of loader net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader @33943b71; domain.Product is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @5be4b0e6)
    at de.cronn.reflection.util.PropertyUtils.findMethodByGetter(PropertyUtils.java:322) ~[reflection-util-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at de.cronn.reflection.util.PropertyDescriptorCache.lambda$getMethod$4(PropertyDescriptorCache.java:178) ~[reflection-util-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at de.cronn.reflection.util.PropertyDescriptorCache.getMethod(PropertyDescriptorCache.java:178) ~[reflection-util-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at de.cronn.reflection.util.PropertyUtils.getMethod(PropertyUtils.java:315) ~[reflection-util-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at de.cronn.reflection.util.PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(PropertyUtils.java:282) ~[reflection-util-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at de.cronn.reflection.util.PropertyUtils.getPropertyName(PropertyUtils.java:290) ~[reflection-util-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at fete.bird.fetebirdproduct.common.querybuilder.QueryBuilder.BuildQuery(QueryBuilder.java:24) ~[main/:na]
    at fete.bird.fetebirdproduct.service.consumer.ProductListener.GetProducts(ProductListener.java:56) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at  ... 9 common frames omitted
```

I am using JDK 14. I know there is a Java reflection API. I can't hard code the field name.

Is there any solution?

Comment: The problem is in [this method](https://github.com/cronn-de/reflection-util/blob/d81374114a310445c03edf49f4eb696e4fa47561/src/main/java/de/cronn/reflection/util/MethodCaptor.java#L40) where the code uses `PropertyUtils.class.getClassLoader()` instead of `beanClass.getClassLoader()`. But given that the author of this library doesn’t seem to know about [`ClassValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassValue.html) but caches things in ordinary maps in `static` fields, I can only discourage from using it in an environment with dynamic code (re-)loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit weird that you want to use a runtime, reflective method to retrieve what is effectively a constant - you know it's literally the string "description" and will always be for a given compile run.

The only reason I can imagine that you want this, is that you're afraid that you're going to rename the field and that you will then forget to rename the string constant(s).

A bunch of IDE-based utilities for renaming fields will spot string constants that have the same name as the field and will mention them ('hey, buddy? Maybe you want me to rename this string constant here too?').

If that's still not good enough for you, you can make a string constant and put it immediately following. e.g:

```
public class Product{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private static final String DESCRIPTION_PROPERTY_NAME = "description";
    // Getter and setter

}
```

and then always use `DESCRIPTION_PROPERTY_NAME` instead of `"description"`.

Surely nobody is going to edit one thing and forget to edit the thing that is right on the following line!

But if somehow you're still worried or this has devolved into some crazy academic exercise - well, it is fundamentally a compile time concern, so use annotation processors which are a compile time concept! Perhaps try [lombok's FieldNameConstants](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/FieldNameConstants).

And if even that is no good, there is no actual way - what you've done there with the `getDescription` aspect is, at best, going to give you the name of the getter. Not the name of the field. There is no way in annotation-processor-less vanilla java without any other tooling in place to use a language construct that will fail to compile if the field is renamed. There is a syntax to refer to a method (`x::y`), but there is no such construct to refer to a field.

Comment: @SanJaisy Also you shouldn't use a compile time constant (i.e. `DESCRIPTION_PROPERTY_NAME` in this case) directly if you expect its value to change. Use a getter instead.

Comment: @AlexR a field's literal name cannot ever change, of course. That is some crazy advice.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I'm not talking about the field name, I'm talking about the value `"description"`. If you expect it to change, you shouldn't use a compile time constant. Because you have to recompile all classes that use it, if you change it. What is crazy about that advice? Should be something s/he should consider, imo.

Comment: @AlexR did you read the question? You should read the question before commenting on answers. "description" is a string representing.. the field name. If you're 'not talking' about the field name, you're not talking about this question.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Yes, I did, it says that the field name _description_ can change and you suggested assigning the field name to `DESCRIPTION_PROPERTY_NAME` and using that constant instead or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @rzwitserloot My point simply is instead of using the constant `DESCRIPTION_PROPERTY_NAME` you should use a getter because if you change the value of `DESCRIPTION_PROPERTY_NAME` you have to recompile all the classes that use that "constant" (and semantically it's also not really a constant).

Comment: Yes, you misunderstood something. It cannot change _at runtime_.

Answer (score 7):

You can try to use `lombok` to generate field names as a constant variable.

https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/FieldNameConstants

```
@Data
@FieldNameConstants
public class Product{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

This will be generated at compile time:

```
public class Product {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
  
  public static final class Fields {
    public static final String id = "id";
    public static final String name = "name";
    public static final String description = "description";
  }
  
  // getters and setters
}
```

And referencing would look like this:

```
Query query = new Query();
if (productSearchCriteria.getDescription().isPresent()) {
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(Product.Fields.description).is(productSearchCriteria.getDescription().get()));
}
```

This has the added benefit of causing a compile time error if you decide to change the field name for whatever reason, catching it early before runtime.

No runtime reflection shenanigans needed.

Comment: How can I add Lombok experimental feature in spring boot with gradle ? what is the dependency

Comment: On the other hand, some folks consider lombok a shenanigan in its own way.

Comment: Since I  can't use Record because record can't be used with Hibernate and JPA. I found a better solution for now

Comment: This is great, but I wonder why this is not part of the JDK